# Circular visualization in R, text and graph overlap

Tags: r

I would like the colours to be behind the numbers on this plot. Right now we cannot read all the numbers because one of the value is too high.
What should I add to my code to make the colours in the background?

My code looks like this:

```
library(circlize)

Category <- c("29.99", "33.9", "37.99", "39.99", "79.99", 
                  "299.99", "379.99", "389.99", 
                  "399.99", "400") #Price category
  

Percent <- c(83.6,70,84,80,92,76,58,72,80.2,72) #Percentage of ratings
    
    
    color = rainbow(length(Percent))
    Category = rev(Category)
    Percent = rev(Percent)
    color = rev(color)
    

par(mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
circos.par("start.degree" = 90)
circos.initialize("a", xlim = c(0, 100)) # 'a` just means there is one sector
circos.trackPlotRegion(ylim = c(0.5, length(Percent)+0.5), track.height = 0.8, 
                       bg.border = NA, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
                         xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim") # in fact, it is c(0, 100)
                         for(i in seq_along(Percent)) {
                           circos.lines(xlim, c(i, i), col = "#CCCCCC")
                           circos.rect(0, i - 0.45, Percent[i], i + 0.45, col = color[i], 
                                       border = "white")
                           circos.text(xlim[2], i, paste0(Category[i], " - ", Percent[i], "%"), 
                                       adj = c(1, 0.5)) 
                         }
                       })
circos.clear()

text(0, 0, "LIKE", col = "#CCCCCC")
```

[image: Circular visualization in R, text and graph in green overlap]

Comment: Thanks, I've just added a simplified version of my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw all the colors first, then draw all the labels in a second loop on top

```
circos.trackPlotRegion(ylim = c(0.5, length(Percent)+0.5), track.height = 0.8, 
                       bg.border = NA, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
                         xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim") # in fact, it is c(0, 100)
                         for(i in seq_along(Percent)) {
                           circos.lines(xlim, c(i, i), col = "#CCCCCC")
                           circos.rect(0, i - 0.45, Percent[i], i + 0.45, col = color[i], 
                                       border = "white")
                         }
                         for(i in seq_along(Percent)) {
                           circos.text(xlim[2], i, paste0(Category[i], " - ", Percent[i], "%"), 
                                       adj = c(1, 0.5)) 
                         }
                       })
```

[image]